# Log DB connections opening and closing with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel app where I've encountered a `[1040] Too many connections` error a few times over the past few weeks. I'm very surprised because my max_connections is at the default value (151), and Google Analytics shows I haven't had more than 30 users on the website at the same time..

I'm struggling to debug where the issue might come from. I'm thinking a starting point would be to monitor when Laravel opens and closes connections to the database, to see if I can identity connections that remain open longer than they should.

Is there a way to detect when Laravel *actually* opens/closes a connection?

(Any other idea on how to find where the issue comes from is also welcome!)

Comment: Question is to broad to answer with this limited information.. As *"The maximum number of connections MySQL supports (that is, the maximum va lue to which max_connections can be set) depends on several factors: ... "* and also *"Increasing the max_connections value increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires. If the required number of descriptors are not available, the server reduces the value of max_connections. ... "* [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/client-connections.html)

Comment: are you using shared hosting to deploy this app ?

Comment: No, I'm on a VPS